# React embedded login implementation using react router v6

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, react-hooks, react-router, auth0

I'm trying to set up an embedded login implementation in React, except the tutorial I'm following is currently using a previous version of react-router, and I'm wondering how to fix it in v6.

Currently, I have this in my App.js:

```
import Auth from "./Auth";
import Callback from "./components/Login/Callback";

const App = ({history}) => {
    const auth = new Auth(history);
    return (
    ...
    <Routes>
     ...
     <Route path="/callback" render={props => <Callback auth={auth} {...props} />} />
    </Routes>
```

and this in my Callback.js:

```
const Callback = ({auth}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.handleAuth()
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
```

how can I change this to make it correctly render the url that I want, where it adds on to "/callback" the access token, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Which tutorial are you following? As far as I have experienced, using react-router v5 vs v6 should not affect any of the things you looking at, other than `Switch` -> `Routes`.

If you are not currently using Auth0 React, I would take a look at [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react) or [this](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/).